# How to initiate numpy arrays with constraints

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create three 3D vectors that satisfy the following 2 constraints.

[image]

The example would be one such feasible solution.

Is there a way to do this with numpy? If not, what package would you suggest?

Comment: Maybe sympy: https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html or pulp: https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/

Comment: By 3d vectors, I think you mean (n,3) shape arrays, not (n,m,p) shaped ones, right?

Comment: can you start with 2 1d arrays, `a` and `b`?

Comment: @hpaulj yes, i mean (n,3). thanks for clarifying

Comment: @hpaulj I want the code to choose between any possible vector (possibly within a range, such as no component greater than 50). so just choosing the size of the norms, i.e. `a` and `b` is one step. But the second step is then ensuring they fit the summation requirement. so i don't know how choosing `a` and `b` helps with that.

Comment: Your constraints just say that the three vectors form an isosceles triangle with the given side lengths.  All solutions are of course just rotations or reflections of one another.

Comment: The `b` in constraint 2 doesn't match the `b` in the `for example`.

Comment: You have 6 equations. So your problem can be solved in 2d, but is underspecified in 3d or higher dimensions. In the 3d case you have 9 quantities, so you have to choose 3, and determine the rest from your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

From matching size arrays, `a` and `b`:

```
In [181]: b = np.linspace(0,10,11); a = np.linspace(0,5,11); z=np.zeros(11)
```

I can construct a set of (n,3) arrays by concatenating the arrays as columns:

```
In [182]: v1=np.c_[a/2,z,b]                                                  
In [183]: v2=np.c_[-a,z,z]                                                   
In [184]: v3=np.c_[-a/2,z,b]
```

They fit the constraints

```
In [185]: np.allclose(v1+v2, v3)                                             
Out[185]: True

In [189]: np.allclose(np.linalg.norm(v2,axis=1),a)                           
Out[189]: True
```

except the `v1` (and `v3`) norms are a multiple of `b`.